# What is the equivalent for new after require in ScalaJS?

Tags: scala.js

I see [here](https://github.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel)

javascript:

```
var D3Funnel = require('d3-funnel');
var chart = new D3Funnel('#funnel');
```

I managed to get the first line working in `ScalaJS` by using:

ScalaJS:

```
val Funnel = js.Dynamic.global.require("d3-funnel")
```

but what should be the equivalent to the second line `var chart = new D3Funnel('#funnel');` in ScalaJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently a bit ugly. To create an instance of a dynamic class, you have to use [`js.Dynamic.newInstance`](http://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/latest/index.html#scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic$@newInstance%28clazz:scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic%29%28args:scala.scalajs.js.Any*%29:scala.scalajs.js.Objectwithscala.scalajs.js.Dynamic):

```
import scala.scalajs.js

val chart = js.Dynamic.newInstance(Funnel)("#funnel")
```

From there, I recommend casting `chart` to a statically-defined API:

```
@js.native
trait Funnel extends js.Object {
  def someMethodOfFunnel(): Unit = js.native
}

val chart = js.Dynamic.newInstance(Funnel)("#funnel").asInstanceOf[Funnel]
chart.someMethodOfFunnel() // statically typed
```

Comment: I read in `ScalaJS` documentation that `Native JS types should be annotated with @js.native for forward source compatibility with Scala.js 1.0.0.`  I see you used `@js.native` here but I don't understand why `Funnel` is not a native JS type so why do we use `@js.native`?

Comment: It is, since it is implemented in the `d3-funnel` library, which is written in native JavaScript.